# sim800 at command post data to server

Tags: http, gsm, at-command, gprs

I'm stumped with sending data to a remote server , I'm able to send a post request but not sure how to add data which is then received by the server.

I've went through the datasheet http://www.jarzebski.pl/datasheets/SIM900_https-121018-1.00.pdf

tried

```
# usual at+sapbr=1,1 set up
+HTTPINIT
+HTTPPARA = “CID”,1
+HTTPPARA="URL","IP-ADDRESS:PORT"
+httpdata=100,10000
# Where do I add the post data ?
+httpaction=1
```

which sends the http post request. But how do I add data - I've tried adding it to the url ?key=val but no joy - any help here will be appreciated

Comment: Good on you for finding a solution! Could you please put the content of your latest edit into an answer instead? Answering your own question is perfectly ok and the right thing to do in this case.

Answer (score 15):

httpdata=100,10000 means that SIM800 should expect 100 bytes within 10 seconds.

This is how I accomplished this using the HTTP client:

```
AT+HTTPINIT
AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://url.com/endPoint"
AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"
AT+HTTPDATA=40,10000
```

At this point, the SIM800 should respond with "DOWNLOAD". Which means it's expecting your data. Send in your data; in my case:

```
{"location_id": 238, "fill_percent": 90}
```

Wait 10 seconds to send the rest of the commands. Then:

```
AT+HTTPACTION=1
AT+HTTPREAD
AT+HTTPTERM
```

That did it for me. Hope it helps.

This is where I got the information from: http://www.raviyp.com/embedded/194-sim900-gprs-http-at-commands

In the backend, using Python Flask, this is the code I used

```
@app.route('/reportTrashLevel', methods=['POST'])
def report_trash_level():
    data = request.get_json()
    database.insert_trash_level(data)

    return Response(status=200)
```

Comment: would you please provide me the code written in server side?

Comment: @alex I've edited the answer to reflect the code I used

Comment: Per the documents, there are a restricted number of headers you can use with this method, so if you have something like a authorization header token, then you'll want to use the TCP connection style that @trojan_spike used.

Answer (score 8):

I managed to get it to do what I need, this code-snippet will likely help others

```
AT+CGATT=1                  # enter GPRS configuration mode 
AT+CIPMUX=0                 # Disable multi IP connection mode.  Single IP cnxn only
AT+CSTT="APN","USER","PASS"
AT+CIICR                    # bring up wireless connection with GPRS and CSD 
AT+CIFSR                    # ip up - gprs working
AT+CIPSHUT                  # Exit GPRS configuration mode

# Now do a post request to remote server api in json format. 
# Change IP_ADDR|DOMAIN for the IP or domain name of your server.  
# Change 2000 to its port
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","IP_ADDR|DOMAIN","2000"

AT+CIPSEND=119 # Num of char in tcp/ip data, \r & \n count as 1 char
POST /post HTTP/1.1
Host: **.**.***.***
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length:23

{"postkey":"postvalue"}
```

Hope this helps the next person stuck on it.

Comment: It did a couple of years later – thank you! The only thing that I don't understand is AT+CIPSHUT (close connections). Is that necessary to do before opening a new connection? In another example that I've seen, it was used after sending the data, which is more understandable.

Comment: BTW, this works on SIM7000, and possibly other more recent SIMCOM chips. I don't think the AT+HTTP… commands mentioned in the other answers are supported anymore.

Comment: Also, `AT+CIFSR` is a bit wonky, it doesn't respond with `OK` or `+CIFSR: <ip>` as one might expect. I've found `AT+CIFSREX` much more reliable (and faster for some reason). It is supported by SIM7000 at least.