# AT command to perform HTTP POST returns 601, Network Error

Tags: gsm, at-command, adafruit

I have a Raspberry Pi connected to an Adafruit Fona 808, using a 2G sim card from Ting wireless.

I am trying to post data from the RPi to a server as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346425/sim800-at-command-post-data-to-server) (which references [this tutorial](https://www.raviyp.com/embedded/194-sim900-gprs-http-at-commands)) but I am stuck. I get an error when I enter the JSON data every time.

```
AT
OK
AT+HTTPINIT
OK
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","https://myapp.herokuapp.com/create"
OK
AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"
OK
AT+HTTPDATA=280,10000
DOWNLOAD

OK
{'foo': '111', 'bar': '222', 'message': 'hi from rpi!', 'xyz': '1'}
ERROR
```

I confirmed the byte size:

```
python
>>> import sys
>>> a = {'foo': '111', 'bar': '222', 'message': 'hi from rpi!', 'xyz': '1'}
>>> print sys.getsizeof(a)
280
```

I have also tried the following:

```
AT+HTTPSSL=1
OK
AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1
OK
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","https://myapp.herokuapp.com/create"
OK
AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"
OK
AT+HTTPDATA=280,10000
DOWNLOAD
```

when I paste in my JSON data, like so:
`{'foo': '100', 'bar': '200', 'message': 'hi from robot!', 'xyz': '1'}`

```
OK
AT+HTTPACTION=1
OK

+HTTPACTION: 1,601,0
```

I am pretty sure this is not due to any faulty hardware; I was able to send SMS messages successfully. Any advice?